# Thymeleaf to access data of joined tables

Tags: java, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have three tables that have one to one relation the first table is the province entity, the district entity which has a one to relation with the province and the person's entity as each person resides in on district.
I would like to access the district information in `thymleaf`.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "provinces")
public class Province {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int provinceId;
    @Column(name="province_name",unique=true,length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String provinceName;
    //getters and setters

 }


@Entity
@Table (name = "districts")
public class District {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique=true,length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String districtName;
    @Column(unique=true, length = 10,nullable = false)
    private String abbreviation;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="province")
    private Province location;
}

@Entity
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    private District location;
//getters and setters 
}
```

service controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/all")
private String viewDistricts (Model model){
    model.addAttribute("listUsers",appUserService.listUser());
    return "admin/users";
}
```

service:

```
 public List<AppUser> listUser(){
        return appUserRepository.findAll();
    }
thymeleaf: 

    th:text="${users.location.districtName}"
```

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:
> Property or field 'districtName' cannot be found on null

Comment: Where is your service and controller? You have to pass instances of your model via a REST controller class.

Comment: Yes, this isn't really related to Thymeleaf.  You are trying to access a property on a `null` variable, which throws that error.  You need to make sure your objects are correctly initialized.

Comment: how can i achieve this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

best practice to handle null pointer exception as follows

```
th:text="${users.location!=null}?${users.location.districtName}:''"
```

But, the root cause of the problem is that the associated object value is null.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).